# How to delete a field from an array using pointers?

Tags: c, linux, menu

Here is part of a code for my menu driven program .
Whenever I try to delete a field , it gets deleted , but I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.
for example : if my list of records are :

```
/*Student Name [0]: x
Student age [0] :1
Student Name [1]: y
Student age [1] :2
Student Name [2]: z
Student age [2] :3
Student Name [3]: f
Student age [3] :4*/
```

and i deleted record 1 after using printf to print the new list becomes :

```
/*Student Name [0]: x
Student age [0] :1
Student Name [1]: z
Student age [1] :3
Student Name [2]: f
Student age [2] :4
Student Name [3]: ( null )
Segmentation fault (core dumped) 

and exits the program.*/


int delete_posi ()
  {
    int posi;
    int c=0;
    int i;                                      
    printf("Enter the position to delete element:\n");
    scanf("%d",&posi);
    if ( posi >= MAX_NUMB+1 )
      printf("Deletion not possible.\n");

    else
      {
        for(c=posi;c<MAX_NUMB;c++)
          ptr[c]=ptr[c+1],
        ptr[c+1]=NULL;

      }                 
  }
//printing records , the struct contains Name,age  
int printlist()
  {
    int i;
    if(student_numb==0)
      {
        printf("List is empty\n");
      }
    for (i=0;i<student_numb;i++)
      {
        printf("*********************************\n");
        printf("Student Name [%d] : %s\n",i, ptr[i]->Name);
        printf("Student Age [%d] : %d\n",i, ptr[i]->age);
      }
  }
```

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: Shouldn't you be changing the `student_numb` variable when removing a pointer? Or the very least check for `NULL` pointers.

Comment: Your error is mostly for this line `if ( posi >= MAX_NUMB+1 )`  when you are doing this `for(c=posi;c<MAX_NUMB;c++)` the else part.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , thanks , inserting  student_numb-- solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming student_numb to be a global, whenever you are successfully deleting one entry, you should decrement the student_numb global. See the below code snippet of the deletion function:

```
if( posi >= MAX_NUMB+1)
  printf("Deletion..\n");
else
  {
    for(c=posi;c<MAX_NUMB;c++)
      ptr[c]=ptr[c+1],
    ptr[c+1]=NULL;
    **student_numb--;**
  }
```